# Best way to check a nil object

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am checking for nil object like this:

```
if let _ = object {
    // Nothing to do here.
} else {
    // There's something that must be done here.
}
```

I would like to remove the part `let _ = object` because there's nothing to execute inside it. Aside from using `if object == nil`, what is the best way using the optional checking to verify if a certain object is `nil`?

Comment: `if object == nil`  *is* the simplest way if you don't need the unwrapped value, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @MartinR isn't that unsafe, since it's not preventing `object` to be deallocated in the `if true` scope? However it has a low possibility.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [guard](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) statement for this purpose

```
guard let _ = object else {
    // Do something
    return
}
```

Comment: yep2, i think this is what I'm looking for. Just figured it out. Thanks

Comment: But why? I do not see any advantage over `if object == nil { ... }`.

Comment: Actually there is a significant difference: The else block of guard *must* leave the current scope (i.e. with return, break or throw): `guard let _ = object else { print("object is nil") }` does not compile.

Comment: @MartinR: The else clause of a guard statement is required, and must either call a function marked with the noreturn attribute or transfer program control outside the guard statement’s enclosing scope using one of the following statements:

return
break
continue
throw

Comment: as Martin R said .... and 'if let _ = object {} else {
    // Do something here
}' is not more verbose at all

Comment: Well, that's what I said, and that's why `guard let _ = object else` is *not* the same as `if object == nil`. – There are many useful applications for guard statements, but in my personal(!) opinion, *this* is just an obfuscated way for a simple if-statement.

Comment: And why the optional binding to the unused variable? *If* you want to emphasize the guarding aspect, then you can write `guard object != nil else { return }`

Comment: @MartinR my note expressed full agreement with you :-)

Comment: @MartinR: If you have a different opinion, add it as your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If your only intention is to check if the object is `nil`,
and the unwrapped value is never needed, then
a simple comparison with `nil` *is* the simplest way:

```
if object == nil {
    print("Warning: object is nil")
}
```

If you want to emphasize that this check is a precondition and you want to leave the
current scope if the condition is not satisfied, then you can use
a `guard` statement. But there is no need to unwrap the object to the unused variable:

```
guard object != nil else {
    print("Warning: object is nil")
    return
}
```